# chmod: missing operand after ‘og=’ Gitlab CI/CD executor=shell

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, chmod

I have the following in .gitlab-ci.yml for pipeline for development server:

```
   stages:
    - deploy

   deploy to dev:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
      - development
    script:
      - chmod og= $ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT
      - apk update && apk add openssh-client
      - ssh -i $ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP_DEVELOPMENT "cd /home/deployer/folder-name && bash dev.sh"
    environment:
      name: development
      url: http://{IP Address}
    only:
      - dev
```

This pipeline is triggered by pushing to dev branch. The pipeline for production seems to working fine with the same code with %DEVELOPMENT% replaced with %PRODUCTION% and - dev with - production. But when running the pipeline with dev branch the following error is shown in pipeline:

```
$ chmod og= $ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT
chmod: missing operand after ‘og=’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

Can someone help me figure this out because I am almost out of options here figuring this out on my own.
Thanks Cheers!!

[EDITED]
Here is the complete yml file that is working in other project

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy to master:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - production
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA_PRODUCTION
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA_PRODUCTION -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP_PRODUCTION "cd /home/project-folder/ && bash prod.sh"

  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://1.2.3.4/
  only:
    - master

deploy to dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - development
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP_DEVELOPMENT "cd /home/project-folder/ && bash dev.sh"
  environment:
    name: development
    url: https://1.2.3.4/
  only:
    - dev
```

Comment: Where are you defining ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT?

Comment: In general, it's best to make sure you use variables in quotes (to avoid globbing behavior) Try `og="${ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT}"` and ensuring the variable exists with the correct value.

Comment: I am defining ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT from variable in ci/cd settings of the project. That variable is a file containing the private ssh key

Comment: Will give a try for this fix and update the post. Thanks

Comment: The fixes that you mentioned did not help, ended up with the same result.
I had used this guide to initially setup the CI/CD for the project. [CI/CD with gitlab](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04)
The funny thing is that same .yml file is successfully triggering other project pipelines but refuses to do so for this one. @sytech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out what was causing the issue. As stated in the digital ocean guide I had set the variable to be accessible by protected branch only but had forgot to make dev branch protected. That is why og="${ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT}" was returning nothing as dev was not protected and was trying to access file for protected branch.
Changed the dev branch to be protected and poof the pipeline started working as it was now able to access contents of ID_RSA_DEVELOPMENT variable.

---

Thanks for your help everyone, much appreciated.